# JavaFX: Customize the layout of composite standard controls like Accordion or TreeView

Tags: layout, treeview, javafx-2, accordion, custom-widgets

While exploring the basic concepts of JavaFX, the following question arose:

Is there a way to customize the layout of composite controls (such as `TreeView` or `Accordion`)?

For example, to achieve a horizontal arrangement of child elements or to introduce animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some controls include API for controlling their layout. For example, you can set the orientation of a [ListView to Horizontal or Vertical](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setOrientation%28javafx.geometry.Orientation%29) or switch [animation on or off in a TitledPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TitledPane.html#setAnimated%28boolean%29).

You can write your own skins to apply to existing controls and modify their layout.
[Public API for control skinning](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/control/Skin.html) is provided in [Java 8](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).
Use the `-fx-skin` attribute to change a skin via css.
More details are in the [JavaFX wiki control skinning section](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/UI+Controls+Architecture).

Using custom skins you can completely change the layout and animations for a control.  See for instance this [carousel skin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Mb15bOwIyE) of a [TreeView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The links you have provided should help me getting started.
But first I should try to upgrade my tools to be ready for Java 8.

Comment: The layout of a horizontal tree is a little bit more difficult than the standard TreeView layout.
In my case, I only see the option to go through the entire tree twice to realize the full layout.
This, however doesn't seem to go well with the virtualization concept introduced by `VirtualFlow`.
It may be easier to achieve my layout requirements with something like, let's say a `TreePane`.